# How to use variables of child in parents static method?

Tags: c#, static, static-methods, static-members

I'm trying to figure out if there is any possibility how can I force child class to use their own variables in static method that was derived from parent.

```
class Parent
{

    public static string myString = "I don't want this string";

    public static void MyMethod()
    {

        Console.Write(myString);
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{

    public static string myString = "I want THIS string";
}

class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {

        Child.MyMethod(); // I want to output "I want THIS string";
    }
}
```

Is there any way how to do it?

Comment: If you used a property instead of a field and it wasn't `static`, you could use the `virtual` keyword in the base class and then the `override` in the inheriting class, or potentially the `new` keyword.

Comment: use the `new` modifier : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx

Comment: @BrettCaswell how `new` would help to change behavior of base class???

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, OP did not state he wanted to change the behavior of base class.. and why would he want to? .... he wants the child to have it's own variable and method of the same name of the 'parent' object,,

Comment: @BrettCaswell " in static method that was derived from parent" - while this statement use "derived" I don't think OP meant "own method" but rather "inherited method". Now I see how one can interpret that as "how to get child to use its own method", but I did not see that possibility when I originally read the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Any** way? Sure, but I'd never do it.  Rethink your design.  Here's a really bad hack:

```
class Parent{
    public static string myString = "I don't want this string";

    public static void MyMethod(){
        Console.Write(myString);
    }
}

class Child : Parent{
    new public static string  myString = "I want THIS string";
    public new static void MyMethod(){
        var old=Parent.myString;
        Parent.myString=myString;
        Parent.MyMethod();
        Parent.myString=old;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Child.MyMethod(); // I want to output "I want THIS string";
    }
}
```

If you are trying to do this because the code in MyMethod is so complex you don't want to repeat it, then doing this will almost guarantee that you'll break something really bad because it'll change the value of myString in Parent while child is doing it's thing.  Very bad.

Comment: why is it necessary to alter `Parent.myString` here?

Comment: So that the static method in Parent picks it up.

Comment: generally, you just cast to the type `((Parent)Child).MyMethod` or `((Parent)Child).myString)`

Comment: @BrettCaswell  It's `static`, so those rules don't apply.  `Parent.MyMethod()` always refers to `Parent.myString`.  `Child.myString` is a completely different variable.  Unless you change `Parent.myString` you won't see anything different.

Comment: the classes are not static.. the methods are

Comment: @BrettCaswell, what's the difference?  Practically speaking the only difference between a static class and a regular class is that in a static class the compiler forces everything in the class to be static.  A regular class can have a mix--but the rules for static fields and methods are the same everywhere.

Comment: you're correct... I'm presuming a usage that isn't depicted.. still, this example includes aspects that are undesirable and not requested.. OP didn't state he wanted to modify the base ('derived' variables).. `Child.MyMethod` should just be `Console.Write(myString);` as well.

Comment: opps.. no, I'm incorrect... he stated using the derived static method.. hmm

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a workaround. Use a singleton pattern and make those fields virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Use instance methods instead. Static members (methods, fields) have their place, but typically don't gel well with OOP design principles.

Furthermore, I don't think your inheritance hierarchy makes much sense.

Have a look at the MSDN guide on polymorphism, which is a good start to understand these fundamentals:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `static` modifier does not apply to subclasses.  The full way to specify a static method or field is to use the class name.  In your example the field you are accessing in both cases is `Parent.mystring`.

Consider anything marked `static` as a global variable or function.

The only way to do what you want is to use instance methods and fields:

```
class Parent
{
    protected string myString = "I don't want this one";

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.Write(myString);
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public Child()
    {
        myString = "I want this one";
    }
}
```

That way if you do this:

```
Parent variable = new Parent();
variable.MyMethod();
```

You will see the original string, but if you do this:

```
Parent variable = new Child();
variable.MyMethod();
```

You will see the new string.

Please also understand that if you change the value of a static field, it is changed for the entire application no matter how you access it.  You can't have some cases use one string and others use another.  That's what instance values are for.